# integration tests on Java, SpringBoot, gradle to exclude from build

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot-test

How to exclude integration tests on Spring Boot test, gradle based on external properties?

tried with @ActiveProfiles. But it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution i found.

You can exclude this based on the external system properties.

```
-Dtest.profile=integration
```

and in build.gradle

```
test {
    if (System.properties['test.profile'] != 'integration') {
    exclude '**/*integrationTests*'
   }
}
```